# Is it possible to merge two ordered factor columns in a way that prioritizes the higher level factor?

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have two datasets with ordered level factor columns I'd like to merge. I would like to merge these columns so that the higher levels in the factor (e.g., "whole"), is "prioritized" over the lower levels

```r
library(dplyr)

level_order = c("none", "half", "whole")

x = tibble(id = 1:4, 
           var = factor(c("none", "half", "half", "whole"), 
                        levels = level_order, ordered = T))
y = tibble(id = 1:4, 
var = factor(c("whole", "whole", "half", "none"), 
levels = level_order, ordered = T))


left_join(x, y, by = "id")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>      id var.x var.y
#>   <int> <ord> <ord>
#> 1     1 none  whole
#> 2     2 half  whole
#> 3     3 half  half 
#> 4     4 whole none
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The output I'd like to see would look like

```r
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>      id var 
#>   <int> <ord>
#> 1     1 whole
#> 2     2 whole
#> 3     3 half  
#> 4     4 whole
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have ordered factor you can take maximum between the two factors.

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(x, y, by = "id") %>% transmute(id, var = pmax(var.x, var.y))

#     id var  
#  <int> <ord>
#1     1 whole
#2     2 whole
#3     3 half 
#4     4 whole
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[setDT(y), var := pmax(var, i.var), on = .(id)]
x
#   id   var
#1:  1 whole
#2:  2 whole
#3:  3  half
#4:  4 whole
```